# Make Synchronus Api inside for Loop

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous

I have an array of Objects/String.

```
this.addtenant().subscribe(r => {
    let a = ['plant1', 'plant2'];
    for (let b of a) {
        this.myService.saveAllData(b).subscribe(r => {
            console.log("result" r);
        });
    }
});
```

and getAllData is in myservice file which returns an Observable.

```
    saveAlldata(b) {
     this.http.post(url,b);
    }
```

The problem is since i am using subscribe the call is being asynchronus, i want to have it something like:
first "plant1" post call has to finish, and then plant2 has to be made. In simple words synchronus call.

Comment: Not what you're asking but if you're doing a POST request, why is the method called GETAllData?

Comment: @SatyaRam do you want to execute 2nd service call after 1st service call is finished or just emitting the call one after another

Comment: After 1st service execution finishes second one should get executed

Comment: Why you want to wait for first service to get finished ? don't to you think it will create performance issue ?

Comment: Because i am using object returned from first service in 2nd service, though i haven't written the code here. The problem is with the second service,if you observe the second service  is inside a loop, so the first object of the loop should be executed with the second service and only after that the second object with the same second service should get executed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use async/await for synchronous calls.

Here is one of the tutorial:
https://www.techiediaries.com/javascript-async-await-tutorial/

A sample code demo would be something like:

```
responseArr: any[] = [];

func1()
  let x = [1,2,3];
  func2(x);
}

async func2(arr) { // make the function async
  for(let i=0; i<arr.length ; i++){
    const response: any = await this.myService(arr[i]); // wait on each service call. This will give synchronous behaviour
    this.handleResponse(response); // handle response in a function if there is common functionality in each response
  }
  reuturn responseArr; // return the final response
}

handleResponse(response) {
  responseArr.push(response);
}
```

Comment: I dont want to return any responseArr, what will be the code, the api calls should happen synchrously, one after the other

Comment: This is exactly an example where service calls are happening synchronously. If you see `func2(arr)`, this is where actually calls are happening synchronously due to await. If you don't want to return a response, it's totally up to you, you can use it as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution by myself. You can use an async await inside a loop, since forEach is not promise aware and cannot be used with Promise. Here is the final code:

```
this.addtenant().subscribe(async r => {
let a = ['plant1', 'plant2'];
for(let index=0; index=a.length; index++)
    await this.myService.saveAllData(b).toPromise().then(r => {
        console.log("result" r);
    });
}
}
});
```

As await works with Promise, so toPromise will replace subscribe()

Comment: Why would you use promises instead of running parallel observables inside `forkJoin`?